# For loop results are not as expected in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

Below for loop results are not as expected on my machine.
I am not able to find out what I am doing wrong.

Please find below code listing for check.bat and softwareList.txt. softwareList.txt is also in the same directory where check.bat exists.

**check.bat**

```
@echo off
call:updateVariables check
goto:eof

:updateVariables
set operation=%~1
echo %operation%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (softwareList.txt) do ( 
set bundle=%%A
echo a. command %%A %operation%
echo b. command %bundle% %operation%
)
endlocal
goto:eof
```

And below is **softwareList.txt** :-

```
maven 
tomcat 
derby
java
eclipse
```

**Expected Results :-**

```
check
a. command maven  check
b. command maven  check
a. command tomcat  check
b. command tomcat  check
a. command derby check
b. command derby check
a. command java check
b. command java check
a. command eclipse check
b. command eclipse check
```

**Actual Results :-**

```
check
a. command maven  check
b. command java check
a. command tomcat  check
b. command java check
a. command derby check
b. command java check
a. command java check
b. command java check
a. command eclipse check
b. command java check
```

Also, How to trim trailing and leading spaces from the for loop result iterations?
I am using below command in for loop and that is not working :-

```
set A=%A:~0,-1%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
call:updateVariables check
goto:eof

:updateVariables
set operation=%~1
echo %operation%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (softwareList.txt) do ( 
 set bundle=%%A
 echo a. command %%A %operation%
 echo b. command !bundle! %operation%
)
endlocal
goto:eof
```

Under delayed expansion , when a variable is defined and accesses within brackets - `!` should be used instead of `%`

Comment: thanks for your quick response. i apppreciate your time. now i am chek ing in file, then go for volley ball ;)

Comment: i added one more statement to trim leading and trailing spaces, but that is not working. set bundle=!bundle:~0,-1%

Comment: @rits - remove `"tokens=*"` - this will work if you have no lines with more than 1 word.